# Image in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a problem with the image in table view cell
The images are downloaded form the Google Firebase and in every cell there is one of that
But when I scroll up or down the images change automatically the index
Here is my code, someone can help me? thanks a lot!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if postsArray[indexPath.row].imageNoImage == true{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageLook", for: indexPath) as! imageLookTableViewCell
        cell.authorLabel.text = self.postsArray[indexPath.row].author
        cell.likesCountLabel.text = "\(self.postsArray[indexPath.row].likes!)"
        cell.postID = postsArray[indexPath.row].postId
        cell.textViewPost.text = self.postsArray[indexPath.row].textPost
        let url = URL(string: postsArray[indexPath.row].pathToImage as! String)
        if url != nil {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if data != nil {
                        cell.imagePost.image = UIImage(data:data!)
                    }else{

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for person in self.postsArray[indexPath.row].peopleWhoLike {
            if person == FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid {
                cell.likesBtn.isHidden = false
                break
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Don't ask questions that have millions of answers on SO already.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very descriptive/well written, but I think your problem is that you are not caching your images.

Try this:

```
    let imageCache = NSCache()
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageLook", for: indexPath) as! imageLookTableViewCell
    cell.authorLabel.text = self.postsArray[indexPath.row].author
    cell.likesCountLabel.text = "\(self.postsArray[indexPath.row].likes!)"
    cell.postID = postsArray[indexPath.row].postId
    cell.textViewPost.text = self.postsArray[indexPath.row].textPost
    let url = URL(string: postsArray[indexPath.row].pathToImage as! String)

    if url != nil {
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage {
            cell.imagePost.image = cachedImage
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if data != nil {
                    if let myImageName = UIImage(data:data!){
                        imageCache.setObject(myImageName, forKey: url)
                    }
                    cell.imagePost.image = UIImage(data:data!)
                }else{

                }
            }
        }
    }
    for person in self.postsArray[indexPath.row].peopleWhoLike {
        if person == FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid {
            cell.likesBtn.isHidden = false
            break
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```